# Determining what is selected in a data grid view and running queries?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, guid

I have a data grid view with my table information in there. Just don't know how to know what the use selected. Then once I have that figured out how to get a value that is selected and run a query to my database with it.

My tables have a GUID and nothing really else to use to run queries off of. Should I use something else or is there a way to use the GUID to find and do querys on it?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET WebForms, Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: What is the datatype of your GUID column in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the _SelectedIndexChanged event?

when using query's below change [GridViewName] to the ID of your gridview

to then get the row use.

```
GridViewRow row = [GridViewName].Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
```

then to get individual cell values you can then use.

```
row.Cells[1].Text;
```

to run a query with it I would recommend using the two like this.

```
void [GridViewName]_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, [GridViewName]SelectEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = [GridViewName].Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
        if (row.Cells[1].Text == "ABCDE")
        {
              //do database stuff here
        }
}
```

If you want to run a query to get children add the PK of your database table to the gridview in the first Column. Then use below code to get the PK value and you will be able to run queries.

[GridViewName]_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, [GridViewName]SelectEventArgs e)
    {
//gets the current selected row
        GridViewRow row = [GridViewName].Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
// gets the the PK for running querys
string PKselectedRow = row.Cells[0].Text
    }

Here is the Microsoft documentation on GridViewRow. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: if (row.Cells[1].Text == "ABCDE")  //Instead of "ABCDE" i need to run a query to find children of the selected cell. I get the rest though

Comment: You can remove the if statement. its a way of validating you have the correct row but as you won't know the row that's selected I suggest playing around with row variable to achieve the results required. Here is the Microsoft documentation on GridViewRow. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow(v=vs.110).aspx